# https redirect to virtual host directory and http not working

Tags: ubuntu, apache-http-server, ssl

System configuration

1. ubuntu14.04 (*64bit*)
2. XAMPP 1.8.3-5

   - Apache/2.4.10
     (Unix) OpenSSL/1.0.1i PHP/5.5.15 mod_perl/2.0.8-dev Perl/v5.16.3

I have read on [new features of apache 2.4](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/new_features_2_4.html)

> NameVirtualHost directive
>       No longer needed and is now deprecated.

So instead of NameVirtual hostI tried other ip-based virtual hosts.

Below changes I have made to work with

#### httpd.conf

uncommented **Include** line inside `<IfModule ssl_module>` block

```
<IfModule ssl_module>
<IfDefine SSL>
Include etc/extra/httpd-ssl.conf
</IfDefine>
</IfModule>
```

#### httpd-ssl.conf

create [apache ssl certificate](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-a-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-ubuntu-14-04) and add log files on respective location

```
<VirtualHost localhost:443>

DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs/wsdl"
ServerName wsdl.local
ServerAlias wsdl.local
ServerAdmin myemail@email.com
ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/logs/wsdl_error_log"
TransferLog "/opt/lampp/logs/wsdl_access_log"
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile "/opt/lampp/apache2/ssl/wsdl.crt"
SSLCertificateKeyFile "/opt/lampp/apache2/ssl/wsdl.key"
</VirtualHost>
```

here is the error log file

#### wsdl_error_log

```
[Fri Nov 21 15:43:12.001231 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5322] AH01906: wsdl.local:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Nov 21 15:43:12.001350 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5322] AH01909: wsdl.local:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Fri Nov 21 15:43:13.001886 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5323] AH01906: wsdl.local:443:0 server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Fri Nov 21 15:43:13.001960 2014] [ssl:warn] [pid 5323] AH01909: wsdl.local:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
```

My problem is

- `http://localhost` >> Bad request
- `https://localhost/wsdl/`  >> not working
- `https://192.168.xx.xx/` >> Secure Connection Failed (Error code: ssl_error_rx_record_too_long)
- `https://192.168.xx.xx/wsdl/` >> SSL connection Error

while

- `http://192.168.xx.xx/` >>  working (just like the defualt xammpp)
- `http://localhost` navigate to `http://localhost/wsdl` directory

P.S *localhost* behaves same as *127.0.0.1* in each condition

Please suggest  What something extra I have to add to make it workful? like

- adding something on **/etc/hosts** or any other configuration 
  or
- um commenting Include etc/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf in httpd.conf

---

### update

created proper certificate 
  Note: write `wsdl.local`

> The most important item that is requested is the line that reads
>   "Common Name (e.g. server FQDN or YOUR name)". You should enter the
>   domain name you want to associate with the certificate, or the
>   server's public IP address if you do not have a domain name.

added virtual host address in **/etc/hosts**

```
127.0.0.1 wsdl.local
```

altered */opt/lampp/etc/extra/* **httpd-ssl.conf**

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/opt/lampp/htdocs"
    ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost _default_:443> <-- added back _default_
ServerAlias www.wsdl.local  <-- alias append with www

<Directory "/opt/lampp/htdocs/wsdl"> <-- wraped directory in "
    Options All
    AllowOverride All
    order allow,deny
    allow from all
    #SSLRequireSSL <-- commented
</Directory>
```

and I notice changes in URL behavior

- **`http://wsdl.local/`** **`http://localhost`** &  **`http://127.0.0.1`** *>>* URL  changed to `http://wsdl.local/xampp/` and display XAMPP main page
- **`https://wsdl.local/`**  & **`https://localhost/`** navigated to wsdl directory (which is desired )
- `https://127.0.0.1/` >> URl turns into `https://127.0.0.1/xampp/` and **Object not found**

But this is still not expected, what require is

> `http[s]://localhost/` and `http[s]://127.0.0.1/` take me to XAMPP main page
>
> `http[s]://wsdl.local` would navigated to wsdl directory

Comment: Um.. http://localhost not working? Try `pgrep "apache"` if apache is running, `netstat -patn` see if it is listening on port 80. Its possible that you have specified 192 address as the listening address. You can change this to 0.0.0.0 - this will allow for the server to listen on all IP addresses. If http is working but https is not working - check if port is listening, if not - configure the service to listen on 443.

Comment: `/opt/lampp/lampp` status >> apache working

Comment: netstat -patn 
`tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN      `

Answer (score 0):

> Step 1: Use OpenSSL to produce the keys that are used to secure your
>   site. These keys are used when encrypting and decrypting the traffic
>   to your secure site.

```
$openssl genrsa -out mydomain.key 1024
```

> Step 2: Generate your own certificate .

```
 $ openssl req -new -key mydomain.key -x509 -out mydomain.crt
```

> Step 3: Keep the pricate key in the directory /etc/apache2/ssl.key/
>   and certificate in the directory /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/.

Note: The ssl.key directory must be only readable by root.

> Step 4: Now you need to edit httpd.conf file in /etc/apache2.

Now this file should include content like this:

```
> <VirtualHost *:80>
> 
> ServerAdmin keshav.mohta@dotsquares.com
> 
> DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/wsdl
> 
> ServerName www.mydomain.com
> 
> ServerAlias mydomain.com
> 
> </VirtualHost>


<VirtualHost *:443>

ServerAdmin keshav.mohta@dotsquares.com

DocumentRoot /opt/lampp/htdocs/wsdl

ServerName mail.mydomain.com

SSLEngine on

SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl.crt/mydomain.crt

SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl.key/mydomain.key

ErrorLog "/opt/lampp/logs/wsdl_error_log"

TransferLog "/opt/lampp/logs/wsdl_access_log"

</VirtualHost>


<Directory /srv/www/htdocs/mydomain-secure>
SSLRequireSSL
</Directory>
```

Don't change Listen 80 to 443 in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf. SSL is configured in /etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf.
SSL is enabled and listening by default with a self signed certificate.

You can get to the default site using SSL just by browsing to `https://localhost` (you don't need to add the port to the end of the URL).

If you want to forward all HTTP requests to HTTPS (which is what I believe you are trying to achieve), you can either add a permanent redirect, or use the Apache module mod_rewrite.

The easiest and most secure way is to set up a permanent redirect. Enable named virtual hosts and add a Redirect directive to the VirtualHost in /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf.

Comment: there is `httpd-ssl.conf` for the Virtual host configuration. Is that okay instead on `httpd.conf`

Comment: I did whatever you have said but now it's block http://192.168.xx.xx ( that was working earlier) now every request(localhost,192.xx or 127.0) goes to wsdl directory.

Comment: I just want to run one site on `https` and rest are on `http`(like normal). that's all

Comment: Note:
Put generated key and certificate on **opt/lampp/apache2/ssl** folder with 664 permission

Comment: I have updated my question Please see.